# Distributed Tensorflow device placement in Google Cloud ML engine

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, distributed-computing, google-cloud-ml, multi-gpu

I am running a large distributed Tensorflow model in google cloud ML engine. I want to use machines with GPUs.
My graph consists of two main the parts the input/data reader function and the computation part.

I wish to place variables in the PS task, the input part in the CPU and the computation part on the GPU.
The function `tf.train.replica_device_setter` automatically places variables in the PS server.

This is what my code looks like:

```py
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)):
    input_tensors = model.input_fn(...)
    output_tensors = model.model_fn(input_tensors, ...)
```

Is it possible to use `tf.device()` together with `replica_device_setter()` as in:

```py
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(cluster=cluster_spec)):
    with tf.device('/cpu:0')
        input_tensors = model.input_fn(...)
    with tf.device('/gpu:0')
        tensor_dict = model.model_fn(input_tensors, ...)
```

Will the `replica_divice_setter()` be overridden and variables not placed in the PS server?

Furthermore, since the device names in the cluster are something like `job:master/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0` how do I say to Tensorflow `tf.device(whatever/gpu:0)`?

Comment: Specifying your own tf.device() overrides any replica device setter in the  outer scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any operations, beyond variables, in the [`tf.train.replica_device_setter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/replica_device_setter) block are automatically pinned to `"/job:worker"`, which will default to the first device managed by the first task in the "worker" job.

You **can** pin them to another device (or task) by using embedded device block:

```py
with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(ps_tasks=2, ps_device="/job:ps", 
                                          worker_device="/job:worker")):
  v1 = tf.Variable(1., name="v1")  # pinned to /job:ps/task:0 (defaults to /cpu:0)
  v2 = tf.Variable(2., name="v2")  # pinned to /job:ps/task:1 (defaults to /cpu:0)
  v3 = tf.Variable(3., name="v3")  # pinned to /job:ps/task:0 (defaults to /cpu:0)
  s = v1 + v2            # pinned to /job:worker (defaults to task:0/cpu:0)
  with tf.device("/task:1"):
    p1 = 2 * s           # pinned to /job:worker/task:1 (defaults to /cpu:0)
    with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
      p2 = 3 * s         # pinned to /job:worker/task:1/cpu:0
```

Comment: Just one follow-up: assuming I am doing between graph replication, if I remove `with tf.device("/task:1"):` can I expect `p2 = 3 * s` to be computed in `cpu:0` for all the different workers?